# Facebook SDK for Windows Phone: InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-7, facebook-c#-sdk, windows-phone

I'm getting this exception when awaiting LoginAsync:

```
await fb.LoginAsync("user_about_me");
```

The full stack trace is the following:

```
{System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
   at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccess(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at FacebookServiceClient.FbServiceClient.<Login>d__0.MoveNext()}
```

I'm using Facebook Client 0.5.0.

The strange thing is that this error doesn't always occur, usually when I start a coding session everything is just fine, but then (after a few debug sessions) this exception popups every time. 
Any thoughts?

Edit: I have this problem even on the SDK github sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not anything to do with the operation itself after browsing the code I found out that the problem is when the browser fails to connect to facebook this exception is thrown.

Comment: can u please tell me some scenario when the browser fails to connect to facebook? One scenario I see is when there is no network. Any more ? 
In my application, I can connect to facebook through emulator but not through app.

Comment: On the emulator you can decide the network speed, if the speed is low enough it will generate a timeout ;)